# Oracle Apex 22.x how to set CSS ID for Menu Item in Navigation Menu List instead of default ID "t_TreeNav_X"

Tags: oracle-apex

I try to set a custom CSS ID for an menu item in a shared component list for selecting and styling with JavaScript.

I thought this is possible with the "ID Attribut" field in an List entry.

But if I paste a string like "myId" in this field it doesn`t seem to work (see screenshot).
[Oracle Apex list ebtry for navigation menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aznmc.png)

If I check with dev tools in the browser the menu item still has not this ID but the default ID "t_TreeNav_4".

Answer (score 0):

The `div` holding the whole menu (ul) has an ID of `t_TreeNav`

And all the menu list (li) has an ID of `t_TreeNav_0, t_TreeNav_1, t_TreeNav_02, ...`

It is the same for across all different applications too.
So, It is not like other region ID which we can set our own, the menu might need this ID for their own CSS and JavaScript.

For my case, I just use these existing IDs for custom CSS styling.